# Adding a colored border (not shadow) to the label text on a Highcharts treemap

Tags: css, internet-explorer, highcharts, treemap, text-coloring

I would like the label text on my Highcharts treemap to be white with a black border, so that it is consistent and clearly visible on all colors.  Is this possible?  I have played with the textShadow options, and it looks okay (although not great) in Chrome, but it looks very unprofessional in Internet Explorer.  See the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k1hohozg/4/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title:  "",
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",            
            data: [
            {
                name: 'Name One',
                value: 20,
                color: "#FFFF00"
            }, {
                name: 'Name Two',
                value: 20,
                color: '#000099',
            }, {
                name: 'Name Three',
                value: 1,
                color: '#007799',
            }, {
                name: 'Name Four',
                value: 1,
                color: '#FFCC00',
            }
            ],

            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '20px',
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        textShadow: "0 0 3px #000, 0 0 3px #000",
                    }
                },
            }],
        }],
    });
})
```

I do not want to use the "contrast" option because I need all the text to look the same, hence white with a black border.  What is the best way to make this look better in all standard browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default Highcharts way to deal with IE rendering poorly text-shadow. It is possible to set useHTML to true and add multiple labels that will be imitating shadow. (Looks fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE11).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yzLavxc9/2/

```
....
dataLabels: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<div class=dataLabelContainer><div style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 1px; color: #000;">'+this.key+'</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; color: #000;">'+this.key+'</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: -1px; color: #000;">'+this.key+'</div><div style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: -1px; color: #000;">'+this.key+'</div><div style="position: absolute; color: #fff;">'+this.key+'</div></div><div style="color: #fff;">'+this.key+'</div></div>';
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '20px',
....
```

Comment: This provides exactly the display output I requested, thanks Kacper!  It's too bad that this requires the useHTML flag, as it is then no longer possible to have the cursor: 'pointer' effects over the text, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with the **textShadow** attribute wich is not well interpreted with IE. However you can add a background on your labels to be more visible :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: "",
    series: [{
      type: "treemap",
      data: [{
        name: 'Name One',
        value: 1,
        color: "#FFFF00"
      }, {
        name: 'Name Two',
        value: 1,
        color: '#000099',
      }],
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'center',
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          style: {
            fontSize: '20px',
            color: '#000',
          }
        },
      }],
    }],
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You can inspire yourself from the documentation:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.backgroundColor

Comment: This solution won't work for my particular case, because I have some boxes that are barely bigger than their label text, but the color of the box is relevant to the meaning of the visualization so can't be covered up by a white text background.  (I have updated the example I provided to reflect this.)  But thank you for the suggestion.